# Plot bivariate map in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gis

I have two maps (matrices), and want to use them to generate the corresponding bivariate map.

The below code illustrates the idea using 'scatter', but because my original matrices are quite large, I need a different solution than to draw each point individually.

```
 red_blue_colormap = brewermap(20,'RdYlBu'); %using ColorBrewer colormaps 'brewermap'
 white2red = newmap(10:-1:1,:); %color map going from white to red
 white2blue = newmap(11:20,:); %color map going from white to blue

 X = rand(13,8); Y  = rand(13,8);  %sample matrices

 figure;
 for i=1:size(X,1)
   for j=1:size(X,2)
     portion_red = white2red(ceil(X(i,j)*10),:); %value between 'white' and 'red' corresponding to value of X(i,j)
     portion_blue = white2blue(ceil(Y(i,j)*10),:);

     subplot(2,2,1); hold on; title('X');
       scatter(i,j,100,portion_red ,'s','filled');
     subplot(2,2,2); hold on; title('Y'); 
       scatter(i,j,100,portion_blue ,'s','filled'); 

     subplot(2,2,3); hold on;  title('X vs. Y');
       w1 = Y(i,j)/(X(i,j) + Y(i,j)); %relative weight of 'Y'
       color1 = portion_red - ((portion_red - portion_blue ) * w1);        
       scatter(i,j,100,color1,'s','filled');

     subplot(2,2,4); hold on; title('Color matrix');
       portion_red = white2red(ceil(i/size(X,1)*10),:);
       portion_blue = white2blue(ceil(j/size(X,2)*10),:);        
       w2 = (j/size(X,2))/(i/size(X,1) + j/size(X,2));
       color2 = portion_red - ((portion_red - portion_blue ) * w2);
       scatter(i,j,100,color2,'s','filled');
  end
end
```

This generates the following figure: https://image.ibb.co/kotP7m/bivariate_map.png

I want to plot the bottom left figure in a more efficient way. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: Something like 'imagesc'.. or anything faster than two for loops and plotting individual markers.

Comment: Have you tried the [`histogram2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram2.html) function with the `DisplayStyle` property set to `tile`?